# A last viewed date time stamp

Tags: feature-request, statistics, views

As the person who asked a question it would be useful to know when a question was last viewed. As a potential answerer it would be useful to know when the question was last viewed before your visit.

Answer (score 1):

Does this have privacy concerns, given that you can also look up when a user was last seen?

```
possible_viewers = User.find_all{|user| user.time_last_seen == question.time_last_viewed}
likely_viewers = possible_viewers.find_all{|possible_viewer| not (possible_viewer.tags & question.tags).empty?}
```

Comment: Good question! I guess if the accuracy is limited to whole days it should not be a big issue.

Comment: Oh noes, someone knows I viewed a question on php variables last. My identity is now compromised!